# Need to post an image to Tumblr blog in android

Tags: android, tumblr

I need to post a image to Tumblr. I read this http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#auth and I come to know I need to get the user info in order to get the blog name. I used the same code I used for Twitter authetication, changed the URLs and get successfully loaded the Tumblr webview. I used the following code to authenticate and to obtain the users info.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.twitter.imageupload.R;
import com.twitter.imageupload.SecondClass;
import com.twitter.imageupload.TwitterImageUpload;

import oauth.signpost.OAuth;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.http.HttpParameters;
import twitter4j.conf.Configuration;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;
import twitter4j.http.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.http.OAuthAuthorization;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Tumblr_Web_View extends Activity {
    SharedPreferences settings;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "GREATEST_THINGS";
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    final String TAG = getClass().getName();
    Button cancel_button;
    public static String usr_img, log_res, log_id;
    private OAuthConsumer consumer;
    private OAuthProvider provider;

    WebView tumblr_web_view;

    String tweet_Sign_in;
    static twitter4j.Twitter twitter;
    public static String userName;
    public static URL twt_img_url;
    AccessToken accessToken;
    SharedPreferences twtuname_pref;

    SharedPreferences userpref;
    public static final String USER_PREF = "TWITTER_USER";
    SharedPreferences.Editor usereditor;

    SharedPreferences twtlogpref;
    public static SharedPreferences.Editor twtlogeditor;
    public static final String TWTPREF_LOGIN = "LOGIN ID";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.tumblr_web_view);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {

            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        tumblr_web_view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.tumblr_web_view);
        twtuname_pref = this.getSharedPreferences("user_pref", 1);
        settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        editor = settings.edit();
        userpref = getSharedPreferences(USER_PREF, 0);
        twtlogpref = getSharedPreferences(TWTPREF_LOGIN, 0);
        try {
            this.consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(
                    Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
            this.provider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(Constants.REQUEST_URL,
                    Constants.ACCESS_URL, Constants.AUTHORIZE_URL);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error creating consumer / provider", e);
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "Starting task to retrieve request token.");
        // new OAuthRequestTokenTask(this,consumer,provider).execute();
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "Retrieving request token from Google servers");
            final String url = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer,
                    Constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
            Log.i(TAG, "Popping a browser with the authorize URL : " + url);
            // Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            // Uri.parse(url)).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP |
            // Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
            // this.startActivity(intent);
            tumblr_web_view.loadUrl(url);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error during OAUth retrieve request token", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when the OAuthRequestTokenTask finishes (user has authorized the
     * request token). The callback URL will be intercepted here.
     */
    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        final Uri uri = intent.getData();
        if (uri != null
                && uri.getScheme().equals(Constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Callback received : " + uri);
            Log.i(TAG, "Retrieving Access Token");

            new RetrieveAccessTokenTask(this, consumer, provider, prefs)
                    .execute(uri);

            // finish();

        }
    }

    public class RetrieveAccessTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Void> {

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private Context context;
        private OAuthProvider provider;
        private OAuthConsumer consumer;
        private SharedPreferences prefs;

        public RetrieveAccessTokenTask(Context context, OAuthConsumer consumer,
                OAuthProvider provider, SharedPreferences prefs) {
            this.context = context;
            this.consumer = consumer;
            this.provider = provider;
            this.prefs = prefs;
        }

        /**
         * Retrieve the oauth_verifier, and store the oauth and
         * oauth_token_secret for future API calls.
         */
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Uri... params) {
            Uri uri = params[0];
            Log.v("uri >>", uri + "");

            String oauth_verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);

            try {
                consumer.setTokenWithSecret(consumer.getToken(),
                        consumer.getTokenSecret());
            //  provider.retrieveAccessToken(consumer, oauth_verifier);

                Log.v("getToken", consumer.getToken());
                Log.v("getTokenSecret", consumer.getTokenSecret());

                Editor uname_editor = twtuname_pref.edit();
                uname_editor.putString("token", consumer.getToken());

                uname_editor.putString("secret_token",
                        consumer.getTokenSecret());
                uname_editor.putString("login_status", "already_logged");
                uname_editor.commit();

                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
                        "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/user/info");
                try {

                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                    System.out.println("httpResponse");
                    InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity()
                            .getContent();
                    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                            inputStream);
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                            inputStreamReader);
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    String bufferedStrChunk = null;
                    while ((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
                    }
                    System.out.println("Returning value of doInBackground :"
                            + stringBuilder.toString());
                } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
                    System.out
                            .println("Exception generates caz of httpResponse :"
                                    + cpe);
                    cpe.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    System.out
                            .println("Second exception generates caz of httpResponse :"
                                    + ioe);
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "OAuth - Access Token Retrieval Error", e);
            }

            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

I got the following error.

```
 06-06 23:06:20.084: I/System.out(20264): Returning value of doInBackground :{"meta":{"status":401,"msg":"Not Authorized"},"response":[]}
```

what I have done wrong?

update: 
Successfully got the user info now. Got the users blog name.

```
public class RetrieveAccessTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Void> {

            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            private Context context;
            private OAuthProvider provider;
            private OAuthConsumer consumer;
            private SharedPreferences prefs;

            public RetrieveAccessTokenTask(Context context, OAuthConsumer consumer,
                    OAuthProvider provider, SharedPreferences prefs) {
                this.context = context;
                this.consumer = consumer;
                this.provider = provider;
                this.prefs = prefs;
            }

            /**
             * Retrieve the oauth_verifier, and store the oauth and
             * oauth_token_secret for future API calls.
             */
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Uri... params) {
                Uri uri = params[0];
                Log.v("uri >>", uri + "");

                String oauth_verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);

                try {
                    consumer.setTokenWithSecret(consumer.getToken(),
                            consumer.getTokenSecret());
                    provider.retrieveAccessToken(consumer, oauth_verifier);

                    Log.v("getToken", consumer.getToken());
                    Log.v("getTokenSecret", consumer.getTokenSecret());

                    Editor uname_editor = twtuname_pref.edit();
                    uname_editor.putString("token", consumer.getToken());

                    uname_editor.putString("secret_token",
                            consumer.getTokenSecret());
                    uname_editor.putString("login_status", "already_logged");
                    uname_editor.commit();

                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
                            "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/user/info");
                    try {
        consumer.sign(httpGet);
                        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                        System.out.println("httpResponse");
                        InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity()
                                .getContent();
                        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                                inputStream);
                        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                                inputStreamReader);
                        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                        String bufferedStrChunk = null;
                        while ((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
                        }
                        System.out.println("Returning value of doInBackground :"
                                + stringBuilder.toString());
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
                        System.out
                                .println("Exception generates caz of httpResponse :"
                                        + cpe);
                        cpe.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        System.out
                                .println("Second exception generates caz of httpResponse :"
                                        + ioe);
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "OAuth - Access Token Retrieval Error", e);
                }

                return null;
            }

        }
```

I tried to post a image to the logged in user's blog. Used the following code. But didn't get the response.

```
try {
                                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                                client.getConnectionManager()
                                        .getSchemeRegistry()
                                        .register(
                                                new Scheme("SSLSocketFactory", SSLSocketFactory
                                                        .getSocketFactory(), 443));
                                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(),
                                        10000);
                                HttpResponse response1;
                                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
                                        "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/"+username+".tumblr.com/post");
                                consumer.sign(post);
                                JSONObject json_obj_val = new JSONObject();
                                json_obj_val.put("type", "photo");
                                json_obj_val.put("caption", "test");
                                json_obj_val.put("source", "http://50.57.227.117/blacksheep/uploaded/Detailed_images/961314275649aladdins.jpg");

                                    post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                                post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                                StringEntity entity_val = new StringEntity(
                                        json_obj_val.toString());
                                entity_val.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(
                                        HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                                post.setEntity(entity_val);
                                response1 = client.execute(post);
                                String response_string = EntityUtils.toString(response1.getEntity());
                                Log.v("response >>", response_string);
                                Log.v("response length >>", response_string.length() + "");
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
```

Got the following response. what is wrong in the code?

```
06-11 16:24:46.312: V/response >>(27710): {"meta":{"status":400,"msg":"Bad Request"},"response":{"errors":["Post cannot be empty."]}}
```

Comment: I see your HttpGet but I don't see where you're sending the token along with the Get.

Comment: thanks Ally. Now I get the user info. See the update. I tried to post the image to users blog. It failed.

Comment: I don't know a lot about Android, but shouldn't you be setting the post data/post parameters some how instead of the entity? Just glancing through some documentation, I think you might want to use setParams() and pass it some HttpParams instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I used the following code and get successfully posted the image to the logged in user's blog.

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse resp = null;
String result = null;
    HttpPost hpost = new HttpPost("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/" + username + ".tumblr.com/post");
                                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "photo"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("caption", "hello"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("source", "url_of_the_image"));


            String debug = "";
            try {
                hpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                        nameValuePairs));
                consumer.sign(hpost);
                resp = client.execute(hpost);
                result = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());
                Log.v("result >>", result);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                debug += e.toString();
            } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Serial try/catch, nasty.. if something fails surely you want to stop at that point?  Why not have just one try/catch and put the sequence inside it, each of those catches will pick up errors individually.

Comment: I need to post image from sd card so i have given file.getAbsolutePath but not working. Can u tell me how to do it ?