# Android Tumblr login issue "JumblrException: Not Authorized"

Tags: java, android, tumblr

Why following code giving me such type of exception **com.tumblr.jumblr.exceptions.JumblrException: Not Authorized**

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968684/need-to-post-an-image-to-tumblr-blog-in-android) , but i am not able to resolved this issue...plz help me

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "TumblrDemo";
    private static final String PREFERENCE_NAME = "tumblr";

    public static final String REQUEST_TOKEN_URL = "https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token";
    public static final String ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token";
    public static final String AUTH_URL = "https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize";
    // public static final String CALLBACK_URL =
    // "tumblrdemo://tumblrdemo.com/ok";

    public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME = "oauthflow-tumblr";
    public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST = "callback";
    public static final String CALLBACK_URL = OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME + "://"
            + OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST;

    private TransparentProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private Button loginTumblrBtn;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer consumer;
    private CommonsHttpOAuthProvider provider;
    private String token, token_secret, oauth_verifier;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(Constant.CONSUMER_KEY,
                Constant.CONSUMER_SECRET);

        provider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(REQUEST_TOKEN_URL,
                ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, AUTH_URL);

        preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        loginTumblrBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_tumblr);

        Uri uri = this.getIntent().getData();

        if (uri != null && uri.getScheme().equals(OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME)) {
            loginTumblrBtn.setText(getString(R.string.logout_tumblr));
            try {
                oauth_verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);

                Log.d(TAG, uri.toString());
                // provider.retrieveAccessToken(consumer, oauth_verifier);

                // token = consumer.getToken();
                // token_secret = consumer.getTokenSecret();

                token = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_token");
                token_secret = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
                consumer.setTokenWithSecret(token, token_secret);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString(Constant.TOKEN, token);
                editor.putString(Constant.TOKEN_SECRET, token_secret);
                editor.commit();

                getUserDetails();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {

            loginTumblrBtn.setText(getString(R.string.login_tumblr));
        }
        loginTumblrBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == R.id.login_tumblr) {

            if (isTumblrConnected()) {

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString(Constant.TOKEN, null);
                editor.putString(Constant.TOKEN_SECRET, null);
                editor.commit();
                loginTumblrBtn.setText(getString(R.string.login_tumblr));
            } else {
                new AsyncTaskClass().execute();
            }
        }

    }

    private boolean isTumblrConnected() {
        return preferences.getString(Constant.TOKEN, null) != null;
    }

    private class AsyncTaskClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer,
                        CALLBACK_URL);

                startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                        Uri.parse(authUrl)));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new TransparentProgressDialog(MainActivity.this,
                    R.drawable.loading);
            progressDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing())
                progressDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        if (isTumblrConnected()) {
            token = preferences.getString(Constant.TOKEN, null);
            token_secret = preferences.getString(Constant.TOKEN_SECRET, null);
            loginTumblrBtn.setText(getString(R.string.logout_tumblr));
            getUserDetails();
        } else {
            loginTumblrBtn.setText(getString(R.string.login_tumblr));
        }
    }

    private void getUserDetails() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    JumblrClient client = new JumblrClient(
                            Constant.CONSUMER_KEY, Constant.CONSUMER_SECRET);
                    client.setToken(token, token_secret);

                    // Write the user's name
                    User user = client.user();

                    System.out.println(user.getName());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ya finally got solution after too much work, i misunderstood between **access token** and **request token**.

Here it is working solution for above issue.Hope it works for you.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button loginTumblrBtn;
    private CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer consumer;
    private CommonsHttpOAuthProvider provider;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private Uri uri;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        preferences = getSharedPreferences("tumblr", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        loginTumblrBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_tumblr);
        loginTumblrBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(Constant.CONSUMER_KEY,
                Constant.CONSUMER_SECRET);

        provider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(Constant.REQUEST_TOKEN_URL,
                Constant.ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, Constant.AUTH_URL);

        uri = this.getIntent().getData();

        if (uri != null
                && uri.getScheme().equals(Constant.OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME)) {

            loginTumblrBtn.setText(getString(R.string.logout_tumblr));
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {
                        consumer.setTokenWithSecret(
                                preferences.getString("requestToken", ""),
                                preferences.getString("requestSecret", ""));

                        provider.setOAuth10a(true);
                        provider.retrieveAccessToken(consumer,
                                uri.getQueryParameter(OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER));

                        consumer.setTokenWithSecret(consumer.getToken(),
                                consumer.getTokenSecret());

                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                        editor.putString("token", consumer.getToken());
                        editor.putString("token_secret",
                                consumer.getTokenSecret());
                        editor.commit();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            thread.start();
            try {
                thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            loginTumblrBtn.setText(getString(R.string.login_tumblr));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.login_tumblr:
            if (preferences.getString("token", null) != null) {

                loginTumblrBtn.setText(getString(R.string.login_tumblr));
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("token", null);
                editor.putString("token_secret", null);
                editor.commit();
            } else {
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading",
                        "Please Wait...");
                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(
                                    consumer, Constant.CALLBACK_URL);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences
                                    .edit();
                            editor.putString("requestToken",
                                    consumer.getToken());
                            editor.putString("requestSecret",
                                    consumer.getTokenSecret());
                            editor.commit();
                            startActivity(new Intent(
                                    "android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri
                                            .parse(authUrl)));
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }).start();
            }
            break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        if (preferences.getString("token", null) != null) {
            loginTumblrBtn.setText(getString(R.string.logout_tumblr));
        } else {
            loginTumblrBtn.setText(getString(R.string.login_tumblr));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();

        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

and put this intent-filter code inside manifest>application>activity (where callback is done)

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="callback"
                android:scheme="oauthflow-tumblr" />
        </intent-filter>
```

**Image sharing on TUMBLR**

```
public void shareImageOnTumblr(final File imgFile, final String caption,
            final Handler handler) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    PhotoPost photoPost = client.newPost(client.user()
                            .getBlogs().get(0).getName(), PhotoPost.class);
                    if (!caption.isEmpty())
                        photoPost.setCaption(caption);

                    photoPost.setPhoto(new Photo(imgFile));
                    photoPost.save();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    Message message = new Message();
                    bundle.putInt("method",
                            UploadActivity.SHARED_PHOTO_SUCCESSFULLY);
                    message.setData(bundle);
                    handler.sendMessage(message);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }
```

**Video sharing on TUMBLR**

```
public void shareVideoOnTumblr(final File videoFile, final String caption,
        final Handler handler) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                VideoPost videoPost = client.newPost(client.user()
                        .getBlogs().get(0).getName(), VideoPost.class);

                if (!caption.toString().isEmpty())
                    videoPost.setCaption(caption.toString());
                videoPost.setData(videoFile);
                videoPost.save();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                Message message = new Message();
                bundle.putInt("method",
                        UploadActivity.SHARED_VIDEO_SUCCESSFULLY);
                message.setData(bundle);
                handler.sendMessage(message);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```